# Swiping on UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, tableview, cell

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let more = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "More") { action, index in
        print("more button tapped")
    }
    more.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

    let favorite = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Favorite") { action, index in
        print("favorite button tapped")
    }
    favorite.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange

    let share = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Share") { action, index in
        print("share button tapped")
    }
    share.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

    return [share, favorite, more]
}
```

I have insert this code to create some actions to do on a single `Cell`, but when I run the project and I try to swipe on a cell the only action possible is `Delete`.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: So are you not able to see all the options on the swipe or you do see the buttons but tapping is not working on it ?

Comment: @ManishPathak I'm not able to see all the options. I can see only the option "delete"

Comment: Has Nirav's answer solved your problem ?

Comment: @ManishPathak yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Signature of [`tableView(_:editActionsForRowAt:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614956-tableview) is changed in Swift 3 to like below. So simply replace your `editActionsForRowAt` with below one.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let more = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "More") { action, index in
        print("more button tapped")
    }
    more.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

    let favorite = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Favorite") { action, index in
        print("favorite button tapped")
    }
    favorite.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange

    let share = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Share") { action, index in
        print("share button tapped")
    }
    share.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

    return [share, favorite, more]
}
```